# Nginx rewrite - not working - convert from htaccess

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

I have a .htaccess file and I'm trying to convert it to an NGINX URL Rewrite configuration. Unfortunately, none of the available converters help. Every time I get either a 403 error or 'No input file specified.'.
PHP 8.1/nginx/aapanel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    <Files .env>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that authorization probably, which I can't get around :(

Comment: "The problem is that authorization probably" - You probably don't need that at all on Nginx. That rule is to get around a security restriction on Apache when PHP is installed as a CGI script. (That rule is also only relevant if you are using HTTP Authentication with your backend application.)

Comment: What is the nginx configuration you are using?